# Is there any way to make VS2013 remember the work item I associated with my last commit in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

It's annoying to have to paste in the same feature's work item for multiple commits while working on a project.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean VS will automatically associated the work item one by one during the  multiple commits which you just need to associated the first one manually. Unfortunately, **no this feature** .

For now, the simplest way still is **adding a mention to the commit comment in the form of *“#ID”* where ID is the work item ID.**

Comment: Will this hashtag notation actually associate the work item, same as using the "add work item" link, or does it just add that text to the commit comment and nothing else?

I suppose I could also create a work item query so I can select it from a dropdown list or the like; I've never done that before so maybe that's not how it works?

Comment: Which version control system are you using ? According to the "commit",  I'm assuming you're using GIT. And for GIT this is not just add a comment. It will automatically associated the workitem. Just the same as using "add work item link"  Details please refer this blog http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2013/01/31/associate-work-items-to-check-in-in-a-tf-service-git-enabled-repository/

Comment: And if you add a dropdown list during the commit, you may have to do some customization or using some extension. Besides, I'm not really understand why you want to create a work item query in your situation. Seems you just want to associate the commit with the workitem.

Comment: No, I'm using TFS; I'm just using more familiar terminology from svn/git/hg. I suppose TFS calls it a "checkin"?

Comment: Yes, I just want to associate it with the work item, but it's a pain to have to paste in work item IDs all the time; I'd rather be able to either have VS remember them for me (which doesn't seem to be possible) or let me select them from a list (hence the query).